# select a json record in postgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, select, nosql

Maybe its very silly, but i can't write a simple **SELECT** statement in  the postgreSQL. Suppose I have table with 2 columns, one is id and doc which is a json field.

```
-----------------------
| id |      doc       |
-----------------------
| 1  | {"bob":{"grades":{"math":60, "physics":58, "art":72}}}
| 2  | {"bob":{"grades":{"math":69, "physics":98, "art":75}}}
| 3  | {"jack":{"grades":{"math":30, "physics":40}}}
```

I want to write a **SELECT** which shows something **bob**'s data like this:

```
-----------------------
{"grades":{"math":60, "physics":58, "art":72}}
{"grades":{"math":69, "physics":98, "art":75}}
```

Whenever I write sth, I take errors like :

```
ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar
```

How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: "sth" isn't an SQL query. What have you tried? What gives you that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is malformed. You probably mean `{"bob":{"grades":[60, 58, 72]}}`

The actual operator you are looking for is `->`, for example

```
select '{"bob":{"grades":[60, 58, 72]}}'::jsonb->'bob';
```

> {"grades": [60, 58, 72]}

Comment: Thanks @Sami, but grades is a real dictionary that i reduced it for brevity. Is it true to write `select my_table->doc::json->'b' from my_table`?

Comment: If it is already in json/jsonb column, you only need `SELECT doc->'Bob' FROM my_table`

Comment: With  the `SELECT doc->'Bob' FROM my_table` the mentioned error rises again

Comment: @ehsantoghian Please show your table structure. Is the column type json/jsonb or just text?

Comment: Solved. The problem was due to the json records when I wanted to store them. The sample records saved as text and not Json. Thanks @SamiKuhmonen